# No able to select particular check box using Selenium (Java)

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, checkbox

I want to click on Store Pickup Available checkbox on following page

```
http://www.target.com/c/pants-shorts-baby-toddler-boys-clothing/-/N-59yk1#navigation=true&viewType=medium&sortBy=newest&isleaf=true&navigationPath=59yk1&parentCategoryId=9976007&facetedValue=/-/N-59yk1&RatingFacet=0&categoryId=139007
```

And the particular HTML part has

```
<input type="checkbox" name="facetId" id="in store, onlineCheckbox3" 
value="10058540" omniture="Store Pickup Eligible">
```

I tried many thing By.id() , By.cssSelector() and xpath also.

Can someone try and tell me the working code ... in-between I will continue trying.

Comment: Does that HTML work? It's not legal to assign two values as an ID to an element, and IDs cannot have spaces and commas. That's not a legal ID. If the actual HTML is like that and you are trying to scrape it, you will have to rely on some other feature. What does the `value` attribute mean? Is it an identifier? With HTML this bad it's possible that XPath selection won't work, but you can try `//input[@value='10058540']` if you think `value` might be an identifier.

Comment: @helderdarocha I tried using value .. but with cssSelector() .. it is not working. I guess ID having space is the problem :\

Comment: It's not easy to parse bad HTML. You can *try* using XPath on other elements, positional expressions and see if any of them works. Perhaps if you can identify an external element to define a context, and then simply select the input it might work. Something like: `//some-element[some-unique-condition]//input[some-relative-position]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the checkbox you want to click is hidden initially.  You can click it with something like this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'in store, online')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Store Pickup Eligible')]/../../input")).click();
```

This will expand the element "in store, online", then click the checkbox labelled "Store Pickup Eligible".

Answer (score 0):

It will select `By.id` which you need to write

```
<input type="checkbox" name="facetId" id="facetId" 
value="10058540" omniture="Store Pickup Eligible">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find this checkbox by CSS using: `[id*='onlineCheckbox3']`. As Richard stated, you must click the category to show the element first. Find this by: `[id=dimensions]>ul>li:nth-child(9) a`. Sometimes clicking an a doesn't work (depending on the html structure), and you must click an element inside the anchor, swap that out for span and it should work. I prefer all CSS selectors when locating elements, but you can use whichever method you prefer.